# How can I access a function from model in template in Django?

Tags: python, django-rest-framework

I have a model 'Post' and this has a function 'total_likes' that counts all the likes on a post. How can i access this function inside my template to show the number of likes? Thank you!

Model:

```
class Post(models.Model):
created_date = models.DateTimeField()
title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='poze', blank=True, null=True)
text = models.CharField(max_length=1000, default='Nimic', blank=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(UserProfile, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
likes=models.ManyToManyField(UserProfile,related_name='likes',blank=True )


def total_likes(self):
    return self.likes.count()
```

View:

```
class ShowPosts(APIView):
renderer_classes = [TemplateHTMLRenderer]
template_name = 'mainPage.html'

def get(self, request):
    posts = Post.objects.all()
    serializer = PostSerializer(posts, many=True)

   return Response({'posts': serializer.data})
```

Template:

```
{% extends 'base2.html' %}
{% load static %}
{% load rest_framework %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}


<form action="{% url 'like_post' %}" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <button type="submit" name="post_id" value="{{ post.id}}">Like {{"How can I access the 'total_likes' function ?'}}</button>
</form>


{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just reference the method like any other attribute. Since it didn't take any parameters, Django will call it automatically.

```
{{ post.total_likes }}
```

Answer (score -1):

Just like you passed `{{post.id}}`, call the function before you render the template, and pass the arg to it